# What is difference between Sequence and Dynamic Sequence in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, terminology, postgresql-10

I have faced an interview in postgres and Interviewer asked me about

What is **Dynamic Sequence** ?

I have answer him about **sequence** and told that sequence number changing dynamically is **Dynamic Sequence**

But interviewer replied that sequence and dynamic sequence are different.

I have searched on google and stack-overflow and found both are same.

So i need difference between sequence and dynamic sequence?

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: I have never heard the term "dynamic sequence". Maybe they are referring to a sequence that is created dynamically e.g. in a trigger.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for comment will also wait and see for other responses

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing a *"Dynamic Sequence"*

- It's not in the SQL:2011 Language specification.
- It's not in the SQL:2011 Language foundation (vocab).
- It's not [in the PostgreSQL docs](https://www.google.com/search?ei=8T9IW6vuBsbi_Ab216P4DQ&q=site%3Apostgresql.org%2Fdocs+%22dynamic+sequence%22&oq=site%3Apostgresql.org%2Fdocs+%22dynamic+sequence%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1533.2515.0.2684.2.2.0.0.0.0.183.183.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.ItBB2_GPERA)

All of that said, there are two different things you can refere to as a sequence,

- Those things generated by internal [`SEQUENCES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html)
- The result of a call to the table-valued function [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)

I would ask the interviewer if that's what he's referring to.

Note: I can't think of any reason anyone would confuse them, but there is a precedence for that. [This guy did eight years ago](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/AANLkTinGBv7d%3D-rU0NUxCrzfMFEn7v2OXe531iCoHnOA%40mail.gmail.com#4b3d8a67575b47d13dfc8b3fe57bd8d5)